# how do I enable string interning in protobuf-net?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I am using v2 rev 421.
When I saved the stream produced by protobuf-net and put it through the strings utility, it discovered many duplicate strings. I am talking about the strings produced by the application, which can be interned, but the string interning does not seem to be on by default.

How do I enabled it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two separate types of interning here; there's interning *while deserializing* -  this is always enabled, so if duplicates are in the *data*, you should only see a single .NET `string` instance in your managed classes, re-used as many times as needed.

**UPDATE for 3.x**
String interning is no longer enabled by default. To enable it set the following in your model.

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.InternStrings = true;
```

There is also interning *while serializing*, to avoid duplicating data into the stream while serializing. This is  ***not*** on by default, for the simple reason that no such behaviour is defined in the protobuf spec; protobuf-net tries to stay inside the spec by default, only using extensions on an opt-in basis.

If you want to enable this for protobuf-net=to=protobuf-net usage, then enable the `AsReference` option for any given string:

```
[ProtoMember(13, AsReference = true)]
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

This uses a protobuf-net *implementation-specific* representation. It won't play very nicely for interop purposes, however. If you need this in an interoperable way, the only thing to do is store the lists *separately* (perhaps in a `List<string>` somewhere), and use the position in the list in your data, i.e.

```
// this is .... uglier, but probably easier if you need cross-platform
public int FooOffset {
    get { return Foos.IndexOf(Foo); }
    set { Foo = Foos[value]; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is something I do not understand. Even if it is a protobuf-net specific feature the protocol buffers stream produced by it is still a valid stream, right? And you can still create the respective .proto spec - if I am correct, this is something still to be ported to v2. I am curious then, what is the difference between .proto without AsReference and .proto with AsReference.

Comment: it'll be the difference between the classic `string foo = 13`, vs `netObject foo = 13` where `netObject` is a separate message-type with a few properties; in this case the main ones that matter are `int existingKey = 1`, int newKey = 2` and `bytes payload = 10`; a new string will be sent with "2=>some unique number, 10=>the string"; repeated strings will be sent with "1=>the number we thought of earlier"

Comment: It would be very interesting to examine the respective .proto file once you port the relevant code to v2.

Comment: OK, I have a question. How do I do it using the model? The thing is that my surrogates are attributed with DataContract/DataMember and I do not reference protobuf-net, except in the sole assembly responsible for the (de)serialization.

Comment: @Mark it should be AsReference on the ValueMember

Comment: Still there is a problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476958/why-string-interning-on-serialization-in-protobuf-net-does-not-work-in-this-examp

Comment: Still there is a problem - http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=194. In the meantime, I worked around it by uncommenting the MetaType.Fields property.

Comment: String interning is no longer enabled by default in 3.x. You can turn it on via RuntimeTypeModel.Default.InternStrings = true;