# Protobuf.NET and listing known subtypes of object: can't add System.String?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm trying to write serialization code for a class that looks like this:

```
public class EventMessage
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Headers { get; set; }
    public object Body { get; set; }
}
```

The 'object' type members in this class hold objects from a quite small (basically, restricted to one assembly + basic CLR types) type set. So I figured i could simply list those classes as subtypes of object class like this:

```
model.Add(typeof(object), false)
    .AddSubType(1, typeof(X))
    .AddSubType(2, typeof(Y))
    ....
```

This way I don't have to embed type information into the serialized message since the deserialization of the object class itself works much like a switch statement - it checks which one of the tags is present in the message and deserializes to appropriate type. I like this, because then I can freely rename classes and move them around assemblies without breaking things.

This worked great in my tests until I started testing headers, which mostly contain string data. I cannot mark string as a subtype of object since I'm getting this exception:

```
Data of this type has inbuilt behaviour, and cannot be added to a model in this way: System.String
```

Is there any way I can achieve this behavior or do I have to embed type information inside messages to serialize such class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

protobuf-net stores *structured* data; `object` is inherently not structured, and it won't let you simply declare subclasses for `object`, nor will it let you monkey with fundamental types such as `string`, which has very particular rules for serialization.

> This worked great in my tests

<s>If it did, that's a bug; there's no way that should work. At all. It certainly isn't a supported scenario, and won't be guaranteed to do the right thing (it could also significantly break things). I will be changing the code to explicitly cause an exception in this case. I'm adding the following, to be fixed ASAP:</s>

Hmmm.... I *though* this was an invalid scenario, but my regression tests highlight that there is some "prior art" for this, specifically: [Why string interning on serialization in protobuf-net does not work in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476958/why-string-interning-on-serialization-in-protobuf-net-does-not-work-in-this-exam)

(which is why every time I answer a non-trivial protobuf-net question, I add it as a regression test, so I wasn't lying)

I guess I shouldn't exclude it, but **please think of the kittens**: that is *not* my recommended way of doing it. I guess I can't kill it now, though. Emphasis, though: I ***cannot*** enable this for adding `string` (etc) as a sub-type. Consider that API message-type only, meaning your custom `class`/`struct`s.

> This way I don't have to embed type information into the serialized message since the deserialization of the object class itself works much like a switch statement

protobuf-net doesn't usually embed type information either ;p Although there is some "dynamic" support that *does* include type information, but it isn't needed for this scenario.

The *supported* way to do this without embedding any type information would be to **encapsulate** the values you want, something like:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SO11641262
{
    [Test]
    public void Execute()
    {
        var model = TypeModel.Create();
        model.Add(typeof (FooData), true)
            .AddSubType(1, typeof (FooData<string>))
            .AddSubType(2, typeof (FooData<int>))
            .AddSubType(3, typeof (FooData<SomeOtherType>));

        var val = FooData.Create("abc");
        var clone = (FooData)model.DeepClone(val);
        Assert.AreEqual("abc", clone.ValueUntyped);
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(string), clone.ItemType);

    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public abstract class FooData
    {
        public static FooData<T> Create<T>(T value)
        {
            return new FooData<T> {Value = value};
        }
        public abstract Type ItemType { get; }
        public abstract object ValueUntyped { get; set; }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class FooData<T> : FooData
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public override Type ItemType
        {
            get { return typeof (T); }
        }
        public override object ValueUntyped
        {
            get { return Value; }
            set { Value = (T) value; }
        }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class SomeOtherType {}
}
```

Comment: The problem with your suggested approach is that I generally have no way to change what headers are included without hacking around source code of other people. I also do not understand how my approach to this is wrong or harmful in any way - I'm serializing a very strict set of events and explicitly defining what structure an object can have in serialization context. So effectively object _is_ structured data here. But I respect your position and I guess I'll have to embed type information to solve my problem.

Comment: Also, looking back at your suggested approach, you're redefining object class here (FooData is inherently the same thing as object, FooData<string> - same as string, etc), it just happens to be elsewhere in the class hierarchy. If object is not structured then how is FooData (non-generic version) structured?

Comment: @VytautasMackonis **everything** is `object`, yet we don't really want to treat that as the root of the global object model. `FooData` / `FooData<T>` defines a **self-contained** part of the type-system, which can't be confused with unrelated types.

Comment: @VytautasMackonis how did you get to "I'll have to embed type information"? I'm not seeing any part of your question that would conclude with that... genuinely interested, as that may be key to the question. Can you perhaps also clarify what you mean by "what headers are included"? Again, happy to try to help get to the bottom of this, but I need to fully understand the context.

Comment: The `EventMessage` class is part of JOliver Event store project. The headers are filled by my code and JOliver Common domain project code. Changing the structure of this class to employ `FooData<T>` kind of data model would be a major undertaking. I technically *could* avoid strings (or primitive types) in headers and still use the subclasses of objects but this does not look a natural thing to do. So now I'd have to choose between changing EventStore code, changing Common domain code or embedding type information to be able to serialize my events. The latter seems the least hacky way.

Comment: @VytautasMackonis rule of thumb: if serializing your **domain** objects gets messy, then write a few trivial lines of code that maps your domain model to a DTO model that **is** trivially serializable. That is the approach I'd be looking at here.

Comment: That's the main thing. The events ARE DTO's. They just happen to be inside the body part of EventMessage class and they are added there by infrastructure code i generally do not control. Then I can supply a serializer which gets called and EventMessage is the thing that gets serialized.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you add a "Message" or similar class that just encapsulated your String that you are trying to embed

```
class Message
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  string Data {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. I think it doesn't matter if it's CLR primitive type, that inherits from object, or some custom type. If it's registered as inherited type, then it should work in any way. As far as I understand generally it serializes in such structure

```
object
{
  A: {..., AA: {}}
  B: {..., BB: {}}
}

class A{ ... } 
class A: AA { ...}

class B {...}
class BB : B {...}
```

It shouldn't affect anything it it add additional inheritance like

```
object
{
  A: {..., AA: {}}
  B: {..., BB: {}}
  String: 'asdf'
}
```

Because you are not changing string serialization, just adding String as inherited object. Same issue would be if I would want to have *int* or any other primtive type