# How severe, if at all, the performance penalty for using the AsReference qualifier?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I have to decide whether I want to shave off extra 5K out of 550K total by qualifying a property with AsReference. After all, 5K is only a fraction of the total - less than 1%. Still, if the performance penalty is miniscule - why not?

Thanks.

**Clarification**

Using AsReference really reduces the size if there are actually shared references. My question is about the performance or bluntly put - the speed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463460/how-do-i-enable-string-interning-in-protobuf-net

Comment: Thanks for directing me to an old question of mine. I have edited the question - added clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the model obviously, and serialization and deserialization will be different here. For moderately sized models the performance **overhead** will be minimal, except of course it will typically have less actual serialization to do (assuming there is a reasonable amount of repeated object instances marked `AsReference`; if there are none at all then the overhead, though minmimal, is wasted). And if the reference means we avoid re-serializing a large branch of data (maybe a sub-collection etc) then we can get some very nice savings for both CPU and bandwidth.

Any cost here is felt purely by *serialization*, since the problematic part is checking whether we have seen the object before. During deserialization it is just pluckign items from a list by index, so very fast.

Also note that I'm assuming `DynamicType` is *disabled* here, as that is a separate concern (again, impact is minimsed).

Re storage; currently a **flat list** is maintained, and checked for *referential* equality. I would like to have used a hashtable/dictionary lookup, but I have concerns about types that override `GetHashCode()`/`Equals`, and sadly it is not possible to access the original `object.GetHashCode()` instance method. This means that for *very large numbers* of members marked `AsReference` (and here I mean many many thousands of objects in the graph) it may slowly degrade (the lookup will be O(N) for a growing list of length N). Changing this to a hash lookup would make it O(1) at each lookup.

Thinking aloud, we could *possibly* do something when we can prove that the type doesn't override (although this involves more reflection, which is itself a pain), or we *could* just trust the user not to make a mess of `GetHashCode()` etc - and use *their* definition of equality to mean equality in the graph. I'm open to thoughts here, but currently *referential* equality is used as the safest and simplest option.

For actual numbers: it depends a lot on your model and size; since you have a handy model and know the size with/without `AsReference`, you are presumably in a good position to wrap that in a `Stopwatch` or similar (preferably to something like `MemoryStream` so you aren't including disk/IO costs in the timing).

Comment: @Marc, rather than doing an O(N) search for already encountered objects in a flat list during serialization, couldn't you do an O(1) search in a Dictionary<int, object> where the key is the identity returned from an ObjectIdGenerator (which uses RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode() internally) ?

Comment: @Anders oh awesome; RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode() is the method I was talking about (without finding) above. With that, I can write a reference-equality hash lookup, sure